# Swift- Check for updates every hour using background app refresh?

Tags: swift

I have been looking around for tutorials on background app refresh all over the internet for Swift, but I can't find any good ones. All I want to do is run some code every hour to check for an update for my OTA app with swift- even when you force quit the app from multitasking. Is this possible?

Comment: Presuming that you have a server that knows when there's been an update, I'd personally use a push notification to push the fact that there's been an update down to the device, rather than regularly polling for something that might not have happened.

Comment: @MattGibson Okay, But just for future reference, how would I do this? (The background app refresh, not the push notification)

Comment: Please read *Fetching Small Amounts of Content Opportunistically* or *Using Push Notifications to Initiate a Download* in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html